# Looking for a better way to design a class for different situations

Tags: mybatis

I am using mybatis 3.2.3 and mysql 5.5 in a spring mvc web application. I am looking for some advice on how to better address the following situation.

Sometimes I need to get fully populated Vip objects for display purposes. So I would use the following:

```
public class Vip {
    private A a1;
    private B b1;
    private C c1;
    private D d1;
    private E e1;

    // ignore other properties for now
}

<resultMap id="vipMap" type="Vip" >
    <id column="ID" property="id"  />
    <!-- ignore some properties here -->
    <collection property="a1" column="A_ID" ofType="A" select="A.getAById"/>
    <collection property="b1" column="B_ID" ofType="B" select="B.getBById"/>
    <collection property="c1" column="C_ID" ofType="C" select="C.getCById"/>
    <collection property="d1" column="D_ID" ofType="D" select="D.getDById"/>
    <collection property="e1" column="E_ID" ofType="E" select="E.getEById"/>
</resultMap>
```

But sometimes I just need a light-weight Vip object with the id of each of those properties (for example updates) since A, B, C, D, E properties are rendered as drop-down lists in JSPs. In this case, I would prefer the following:

```
public class Vip {
    private Long idOfA;
    private Long idOfB;
    private Long idOfC;
    private Long idofD;
    private Long idOfE;

    // ignore other properties for now
}

<resultMap id="vipMap" type="Vip" >
    <id column="ID" property="id"  />
    <!-- ignore some properties here -->
    <result column="A_ID" property="idOfA" />
    <result column="B_ID" property="idOfB" />
    <result column="C_ID" property="idOfC" />
    <result column="D_ID" property="idOfD" />
    <result column="E_ID" property="idOfE" />
</resultMap>
```

It seems like I need to keep both resultMaps and merge the above 2 versions of the Vip class so that I can handle different cases differently. Is there a more elegant way for this situation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll use the first approach along with lazy-loading.